# Can timestamp take system time in the left over fields?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table dummy.

`create table dummy(id numeric,date timestamp);`

So if data sent into Timestamp column is of format 2021-09-08. Then the data will be inserted as

`2021-09-08 00:00:00`

So is there a way, Where Postgres can take the Left over fields(HH:MM:SS) as the current system time along with the date? Something like

`2021-09-08 11:34:00`

As we don't want leave the time-fields blank, Which is almost same as date datatype!!

Comment: I hope you don't really have a column named "date" - that's horrible name for a column.

Comment: Don't use `timestamp` as data type, use `date`. Rather than shoving two different things into a single column, use a separate column of type `time` for the current time. Then you don't need a trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I agree. But had just taken it for example.

Comment: Ok. But already many table are on the fly in production. @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a trigger for that:

First a trigger *function* to check for a "zero time" and then adjust it with the current time.

```
create or replace function adjust_time()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  if new.date::time = time '00:00:00' then 
    new.date := new.date::date + localtime;
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The function checks if the given time stamp (confusingly named "date") has a time at midnight. If that is the case it overwrites that time with the current time.

Then you need a trigger:

```
create trigger adjust_time_trigger
before insert on dummy
for each row execute procedure adjust_time();
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7554f0a584b295c0244646b226aff752)